# Lipschitz Extension of Multivariate Function

Tags: calculus

Let $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n $ be an non-empty open  set. 
 QUESTION: I believe that if we let  $\phi: D\to \mathbb{R}, t\mapsto \phi (t)$  be  a Lipschitz continuous function on $D$ , then we can always find a function
$$h:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}, t\mapsto h( t ),$$
which satisfys
1) $h( x )=\phi( x ), \forall x\in D;$
2) $h$ is Lipschitz continous on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
( I call $h$ as a *Lipschitz extension* of $g$ ). But I cannot think of a proof.
Any help would be appreciated.
P.s. The following is a part of my original question, which has been already solved:
 Consider the  function $g:D\to \mathbb{R},\  t\mapsto g(t),$ which has continuous first order partial derivatives. Then prove that in general we cannot find a function $f$，
$$f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}, t\mapsto f(t),$$
which satisfys
1) $f(x)=g(x), \forall x\in D \ ;$
2) $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^n.$ 
 @zhw. has given a counter-example in the comment.

Comment: Do you think $f(x) = 1/x$ on $D=(0,1)$ has a differentiable extension to the whole real line?

Comment: @ zhw. :Well, you've solved my first question ! And I'll edit my post.

Comment: On the second question, do you assume $f$ is Lipschitz on $D$?

Comment: @zhw. :Actually the second question contains two smaller ones... I'll edit it now.

Comment: @ zhw. : I made a mistake in my previous post, in which I hint that differential function on an open set must be Lipschitz continous. This is incorrect, and I've corrected it now.